# Regular expression help for vcf file

Tags: regex, vcf-vcard

I have contacts in single vcf file as

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:XYZ
N:XYZ;;;;
TEL;TYPE=CELL:0123456789
END:VCARD
```

I used vcard splitter to split them into vcf files with single contact so that I can add them on my s60 nokia phone. 
Since the `FN` and `N` values are same for *many* contacts, the name is repeated twice on the contact list. So I want to write a regular expression for **removing** `FN:` values for each `VCARD`. Can someone give me the regular expression for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.3.html) for this task:

1. Goto the search menu Ctrl+F and there to the "Mark" tab. Check "Bookmark
   line".
2. Check the regular expression option
3. Then just enter `^FN:` as search term and click "Mark All"

   **==> All lines containing the search term are bookmarked.**

   `^` Is an anchor that matches the start of the row.
4. Now go to the Menu "Search - Bookmark - Remove Bookmarked lines"

   **==> All marked lines are gone.**

Comment: Thanks stema, but the splitter is showing problems without FN: entry so what should I do to have FN: values as NULL

Comment: I have no idea, try maybe replacing `^FN:.*` with "FN:"

Comment: yeah it worked but it N: value was to set to NULL not FN: Thank You very much, BTW i checked your blog very helpful

Answer (score 0):

What stema says, or if you like the cool tools:

```
sed -i "s/^FN:.*\n$//" *.vcf
```